# Cycle through pivot function skips the Else clause in If statement

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

When I run this macro to create emails from the data flowing from the pivot table, the program only runs through the If statement. If that is false then it doesn't move on to the Else statement. As a result the email prints incorrect words from "my_message" and "result".

In the Cycle through pivot function, I include the email sub so it runs through that code. Do I also need to include the If and Else statements?

```vb
Public Sub email()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object''

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng2 = Nothing
    'On Error Resume Next
    ' Only send the visible cells in the selection.
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Set rng = Selection
    
    ' You can also use a range with the following statement.
    ' Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'On Error GoTo 0

    'If rng Is Nothing Then
    '   MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
    '  vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    '  Exit Sub
    'End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    
    If Range(Sheet1!I20) >= 0 Then
        my_message = "receive"
        result = "from"
    Else
        If Range(Sheet1!I20) < 0 Then
            my_message = "pay"
            result = "to"
        End If
    End If
      
    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "default@gmail.com"
        .To = Range("MailTo").Value
        .CC = Range("MailCC").Value
        '.BCC = ""
        .Subject = Range("MailSubject").Value
        .HTMLBody = "<font face='arial' size=2>" & "Please confirm that Organization is due to " & my_message & " " & FormatCurrency(Range("Sheet1!I20")) & " on value date " & Range("Sheet1!I15").Value & " " & result & " " & Range("Sheet1!I18").Value & "." & "</font>" & RangetoHTML(rng)
        .display
        ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
        ' display the e-mail message.
        '.Send
    End With
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook
 
TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
 
'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)

With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    .Cells.Select
    .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    '.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
 
'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
  SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
  Filename:=TempFile, _
  Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
  Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
  HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With
 
'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")
 
'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
 
'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile
 
Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function


Sub Cycle_through_pivot()
'cycles through every item in the Page field (Report Filter)
'and runs the email command
'assumes one page field exists

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("Table_Confirmations_Database.accdb_1").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
'pt.ClearAllFilters
pt.PivotCache.Refresh
pt.ClearAllFilters
For Each pf In pt.PageFields
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        pt.PageFields(pf.Name).CurrentPage = pi.Name
        email     
    Next pi
Next pf
pt.PageFields(1).CurrentPage = pt.PageFields(1).PivotItems(1).Name
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Sheets("Confirmations").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
End Sub
```

---

I removed `On Error Resume Next` and pulled an error on

```
If Range(Sheet1!I20) >= 0 Then
```

saying

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Working as expected after

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I20")
```

Comment: I can't find an `Else` statement in your code

Comment: I assume that you expect that either the `If Range(Sheet1!I20) >= 0 Then`-part is executed or the `If Range(Sheet1!I20) < 0 Then`-part. However, you set `On Error Resume Next` and likely hide a runtime error - remove this and check what is really going on.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Apologies, it is updated.

Comment: @FunThomas I removed On Error Resume Next and pulled an error on 'If Range(Sheet1!I20) >= 0 Then' saying "Sheet1!I20 = <Object doesn't support this property or method>"

Comment: And there you have it: Your problem has absolute nothing to do with `If-ElseIf`. You simply need to learn how to access the value of a cell in VBA - which is different to Excel.  Try, for example, `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I20")`

Comment: Alright now it is working as expected after.